# Dynamically creates TextView boxes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I want to create multiple TextView boxes dynamically, If i enter 2 in the Edittext it wants to create 2 TextView, If i enter 5 in the EditText it wants to create 5 TextView and so on... can anyone help me...

Thanks in advance.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to get the parent layout.if it is ,say LinearLayout means,you can add the textview by using addView(view).

```
letterTextView = new TextView[length];
for (int Index = 0; Index < length; Index++) 
        {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 25, 0);
            letterTextView[Index] = new TextView(FriendsPanel.this);
            letterTextView[Index].setTextSize(20);
            letterTextView[Index].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            letterTextView[Index].setText("TextView"+letterIndex);

            linearLayout.addView(letterTextView[Index], layoutParams);
        }
```

Comment: yes.if you thought the answer is helpful to you,accept the answer.